# Using a file class and it with a max heap method?

Tags: java

I have an assignment for class, where I have to create a file like this:

```
098765
Henry M. Anthony
32000.00
Accounting
Manager
15
```

but with 5 other employees.
I need to use a max heap method to sort this. I created an employee class. The program should sort the method and display it in a new file.

```
public Employee(String id, String name, double salary, String department, String position, int years)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.department = department;
    this.position = position;
    this.years = years;
}

public void setID(String id){ 
    this.id = id; 
}
public String getID(){ 
    return id; 
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name; 
}
public String getName(){
    return name; 
}
public void setSalary(double salary){
    this.salary = salary; 
}
public double getSalary(){
    return salary; 
}
public void setDepartment(String department){ 
    this.department = department; 
}
public String getDepartment(){ 
    return department; 
}
public void setPosition(String position){
    this.position = position;
}
public String getPosition(){
    return position; 
}
public void setYears(int years){ 
    this.years = years; 
}  
public int getYears(){ 
    return years; 
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Identification " + this.id + "\nName: " + this.name + "\nSalary: " 
            + this.salary + "\nDepartment: " + department + "\nPosition: " 
            + position + "\nYears of Service: " + years;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to use the information in a file and assign them to my employee class or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: What you've (correctly) created is a POJO (plain old Java object) which can _encapsulates_ a single employee.  How do you plan to read the employee data?

Comment: Im trying to sort by the salary

Comment: Sorting is perhaps the second (or third) step.  First you need a way to load the data, and you've provided no information about this.